# How to make animation with flip image, scale and position

Tags: css

How to make animation with flip image, scale and change position like in the choise of app in Apple Store?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at [jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) there are a ton of examples on the site.